# Consulta no SQL SERVER 2017

Tags: sql-server, select

Preciso realizar uma consulta no SQL Server 2017, onde preciso trazer as seguintes informações: `Codigo do chamado`, `Data Abertura`, `Interação`, `Analista`, `UltimaInteração`(seria a data da última interação) e `Empresa`; preciso dessas informações somente dos chamados que estão abertos, utilizei o filtro(`where`) no campo `sta_codigo = '1'` que significa que o chamado esta aberto, pois o numero 1 representa o código de chamados em aberto. Porém, quando eu tento realizar o `select`, ele traz apenas todos os chamados abertos, com todas as interações, porém eu só quero a última interação que o chamado que está em aberto teve.

Segue o select que eu fiz:

```
select c.cha_codigo [Codigo do chamado], c.cha_dtabertura as [Data 
Abertura],
Convert(varchar(5000),i.int_descricao) as [Interação], u.usu_nome 
[Analista], 
r.int_dtinteracao as UltimaInteração,
e.emp_fantasia as [Empresa]
from (select distinct max(int_dtinteracao) as int_dtinteracao from 
interacoes) as r, interacoes as i
inner join chamados as c on c.cha_codigo = i.cha_codigo
inner join usuario as u on  u.usu_cod  = i.log_codigo 
inner join empresa as e on e.emp_codigo = c.emp_codigo
where c.sta_codigo = '1'
group by i.cha_codigo, c.cha_codigo, c.cha_dtabertura,  
Convert(varchar(5000), i.int_descricao), u.usu_nome, e.emp_fantasia, 
r.int_dtinteracao
Order By c.cha_codigo desc
```

[image: Resultado da query]

Comment: Você irá usar o `MAX`. Veja mais aqui [Operadores Max, Min, Count, Update e Delete com Subqueries - Union e Subquery](https://www.devmedia.com.br/operadores-max-min-count-update-e-delete-com-subqueries-union-e-subquery-sql-server-2008-parte-3/19168)

Comment: Além do que o @rbz comentou, quem lê na sua pergunta *"Utilizando o filtro de chamados em aberto"* não faz o menor ideia do que é isso.. .você comentou algo que você conhece, mas para nós que estamos lendo não faz sentido, precisaria explicar melhor e claro colocar a estrutura da tabela. De qualquer forma, isso você resolve no `where`, e para trazer apenas o um valor, no caso "o último", você pode usar `max`

Comment: Ola Ricardo, desculpa por não explicar direito, já estou arrumando.

Comment: Ola rbz, eu já realizei o MAX no Where, porem ele traz apenas 1 registro, eu preciso que o select traga todos os chamados em abertos, representado pelo c.sta_codigo = '1' onde 1 é o codigo dos chamados que estão abertos, e desses chamados em aberto, trazer apenas a ultima interação, pois os chamados podem ter 'n' interações, porem eu só quero a ultima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só precisa utilizar a cláusula `EXISTS` em conjunto com `NOT` no `WHERE` para determinar que quer apenas a interação que não possui  ou com data maior:

```
SELECT c.cha_codigo [Codigo do chamado]
      -- DEMAIS CAMPOS CAMPOS
  FROM chamados c
      INNER JOIN interacoes i ON i.cha_codigo ON i.cha_codigo
      -- DEMAIS JOINS
WHERE c.sta_codigo = '1'
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM interacoes i2
                  WHERE i2.cha_codigo = c.cha_codigo
                    AND i2.int_dtinteracao > i.int_dtinteracao)
```

---

> [`EXISTS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189259(v=sql.105).aspx)
>
> Quando uma subconsulta é apresentada com a palavra-chave `EXISTS`, a subconsulta funciona como um teste de existência. A cláusula `WHERE` da consulta externa testa se as linhas retornadas pela subconsulta existem. A subconsulta não produz de fato nenhum dado; ela retorna um valor `TRUE` ou `FALSE`.

Comment: Funcionou Sorack, muito obrigado. !

Comment: @JoãoPedroFernandes Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

O código funcionou com a orientação do Sorack.
O código ficou assim:

```
select c.cha_codigo [Codigo do chamado], c.cha_dtabertura as [Data Abertura],
Convert(varchar(5000),i.int_descricao) as [Interação], u.usu_nome [Analista], 
i.int_dtinteracao as UltimaInteração,
e.emp_fantasia as [Empresa]
from interacoes as i
inner join chamados as c on c.cha_codigo = i.cha_codigo
inner join usuario as u on  u.usu_cod  = i.log_codigo 
inner join empresa as e on e.emp_codigo = c.emp_codigo
where c.sta_codigo = '1' AND NOT EXISTS
(Select 1 from interacoes i2 where i2.cha_codigo = c.cha_codigo and i2.int_dtinteracao > i.int_dtinteracao)
group by i.cha_codigo, c.cha_codigo, c.cha_dtabertura,  Convert(varchar(5000), i.int_descricao), u.usu_nome, e.emp_fantasia, 
i.int_dtinteracao
Order By c.cha_codigo desc
```